# Change value in firestore via javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set the attribute in my firestore via script. I have a small login application. When the user is logging in and if the ticket is false, the ticket should change to true and the firstore should be informed about that status. 
How could I give firestore the information that the variable from the certain user is true  and it should set it in the firestore also true? Thank you in advance!

```
function signIn() {
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;


  const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass);
  promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function (user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("login_div").style.visibility = "hidden";

      var docRef = await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

      // Get the data from the user
      await docRef.get().then(async function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {

          ticket = await doc.data().ticket;
          if(!ticket) {
                // how to set the ticket = true if it is false
          }

        } else {

        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });




    } else {

      ...

    }
  });
```

Comment: You have three `await` and one `async` keyword in your code, yet none of those seem meaningful. Please study what `async` and `await` do carefully, or you'll just be shooting yourself in the foot with it.

Comment: What problem do you have [writing the data to Firestore(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the user document using the `docRef`.

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) provide the following example for updating a document:

```
let setWithOptions = cityRef.set({
  capital: true
}, {merge: true});
```

Applied to your use case it would look like this:

```
docRef.set({
  ticket: true
}, {merge: true});
```

Passing { merge: true } means that the original document won't be overwritten but only modified values will be replaced.